# Amazon aws ec2 network tomcat issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I had the same problem as many others not being able to connect to tomcat port 8080

I had tried everything suggested eg security groups.

What I then did was I created the amazon linux instance (instead of the redhat)

And this worked !! I did the same thing for both instances: added tcp port 8080 in security group

Looking at my iptables does this give a clue?

Bad redhat instance sudo iptables -L

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-61 ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Good amazon linux:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-36-174 ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

It was frustrating for a couple of hours but now with Amazon-linux working I can proceed again. whew!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My EC2 Security Group Inbound Configurations are as follows and port 8080 works fine.
It should be Type-Custom TCP Rule, Protocol- TCP

The below image will show you a screen shot of my EC2 Security Group Inbound Configurations
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is the current contents of iptables including my latest attempt to open 8080

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-61 ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```